# How to render hasMany relationship data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How can I get the following example code to render not just the person data but also the phone numbers of that person when rendering the URL /#/persons/1. I try to loop though the phone numbers with `{{#each phoneNumber in phoneNumbers}}` but there has to be a fundamental understanding error on my side.

Right now I only get:

[image]

app.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
  rootElement: '#container'
});

// Router
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('persons', function() {
    this.resource('person', { path: ':person_id' });
  });
  this.resource('phoneNumbers', function() {
    this.resource('phoneNumber', { path: ':phone_number_id' });
  });
});

App.PersonsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Person.find();
  }
});

App.PhoneNumbersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.PhoneNumber.find();
  }
});

// Models
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  phoneNumbers: DS.hasMany('App.PhoneNumber')
});

App.PhoneNumber = DS.Model.extend({
  number:  DS.attr('string'),
  person: DS.belongsTo('App.Person')
});

App.Person.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 1,
  firstName: 'X',
  lastName: 'Smith'
}, {
  id: 2,
  firstName: 'Y',
  lastName: 'Smith'
}];

App.PhoneNumber.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 1,
  person_id: 1,
  number: '20'
}, {
  id: 2,
  person_id: 1,
  number: '23'
}, {
  id: 3,
  person_id: 2,
  number: '42'
}];
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Phone book</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='container'></div>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
      {{outlet}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="persons">
      <p>All people:</p>
      <ul>
        {{#each controller}}
          <li>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
      {{outlet}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="person">
      <h1>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h1>
      {{#if phoneNumbers.length}}
        <ul>
          {{#each phoneNumber in phoneNumbers}}
            <li>{{phoneNumber.number}}</li>
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
      {{/if}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="phone_numbers">
      <ul>
        {{#each controller}}
          <li>{{number}}</li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
      {{outlet}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="phone_number">
      <h1>{{number}}</h1>
    </script>    

  </body>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ember.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ember-data.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ember-data doesn't act like ActiveRecord in this regard: when you use `has_many` you have to have a property that is an array of `id`s for the records. It isn't enough to have a foreign key for the owner on the reciprocal model.

try adding `phoneNumbers: [1, 2]` to your first `Person` fixture, and `phoneNumbers: [3]` to the second.

If you were using the RESTAdapter, those key names would be `phone_number_ids` instead. If you use `active_model_serializers` you can use the `embed` feature to automatically include an array of ids.

Comment: Changing the Fixtures to the following code didn't make a difference for #/persons/1
App.Person.FIXTURES = [{
      id: 1,
      firstName: 'X',
      lastName: 'Smith',
      phone_number_ids: [1, 2]
    }, {
      id: 2,
      firstName: 'Y',
      lastName: 'Smith',
      phone_number_ids: [3]
    }];

    App.PhoneNumber.FIXTURES = [{
      id: 1,
      person_id: 1,
      number: '20'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      person_id: 1,
      number: '23'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      person_id: 2,
      number: '42'
    }];

Comment: Ah, ok the FixtureSerializer works slightly differently. Change those to `phoneNumbers: [1, 2]` etc.